# Unable to change port number in Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

My Bitbucket instance is running in an Ubuntu server.

The initial installation was done by following the wizard and in that moment it was set the default port 7990.

Now I would like to change it to use the port 443, so as per the [official documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/changing-the-port-that-bitbucket-server-listens-on-776640049.html) it can be easily done by changing the value `server.port` in the `shared/bitbucket.properties` file.

However, after that change, the server is not even listening in the new configured port.

Bitbucket is started as root user.

Why is bitbucket not taking into account the port modification?

Comment: The port 443 is used by SSH, I think this is the issue. Have you tested with another port (7999 for example)? Have you restarted the server after the change?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira SSH uses port 22, 443 is normally for HTTPS. I have restarted the service after the change and still not listening on port 443.

Comment: Sorry, I meant HTTPS. Have you tried to change to another port (like 7999 for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed after configuring a Nginx server which will do relay between port 7990 and 443.

Config bitbucket:

```
server.port=7990
server.proxy-name=******************
server.proxy-port=443
server.scheme=https
jdbc.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost\:5432/bitbucket
jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.user=******************
jdbc.password=*************
```

Config Nginx:

```
    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass              http://localhost:7990;
                proxy_redirect          off;
                server_tokens           off;
            proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
 }

server {
    listen       443 default ssl http2;
    server_name  ******************;

ssl_certificate "******************";
ssl_certificate_key "******************";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {

            proxy_pass              http://localhost:7990;

            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_redirect          off;

    }
}
```